# Import jar into Kotlin multiplatform with gradle

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to figure out the best way to import a jar with Kotlin Multiplatform with Gradle. I have tried doing an `implementation(file("path))` in my JVM source set, but that has not worked for me.

Background: There is a Java project that uses Maven and not Gradle to publish so it does not have the metadata necessary so I downloaded the jars. It does recognize the jar in the Android source set.

Has anyone done this successfully?

```kotlin
kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        publishLibraryVariants("release")
    }
    jvm("desktop") {

        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }
        tasks.withType(Test::class.java) {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }

        tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }
        attributes {
            this.attribute(Attribute.of("DESKTOP", String::class.java), "DESKTOP")
        }
    }

    jvm("jvm") {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }

        tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(compose.runtime)
                api(compose.foundation)
                api(compose.material)
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
                implementation(CiCdDependencies.GEOSPATIAL_COMMON)
                implementation(ThirdPartyDependencies.JTS.TOPOLOGY_SUITE)
                implementation(ThirdPartyDependencies.SqlDelight.SQL_DELIGHT_COROUTINE)
                implementation(ThirdPartyDependencies.SqlDelight.SQL_DELIGHT_PRIMITIVE)
                implementation(KotlinDependencies.IMMUTABLE_COLLECTION)
                implementation("com.ashampoo:kim:0.5.1")
                implementation(ThirdPartyDependencies.KorLibs.KORIM)
                implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))

            }
        }

        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(TestDependencies.MOCKK)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_PLATFORM)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_API)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_PARAMS)
                runtimeOnly(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_ENGINE)
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependsOn(jvmMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(KotlinDependencies.COROUTINE)
                implementation(AndroidDependencies.COROUTINE_ANDROID)
                implementation(AndroidDependencies.CORE)
                implementation(AndroidDependencies.APP_COMPAT)
                implementation(AndroidDependencies.MULTI_DEX)
                implementation(AndroidDependencies.COMPOSE_ACTIVITY)
                implementation(CiCdDependencies.GEOSPATIAL_ANDROID)
                implementation(AndroidDependencies.SQL_DELIGHT_ANDROID_DRIVER)
                implementation(ThirdPartyDependencies.JTS.TOPOLOGY_SUITE)
            }
        }

        val androidUnitTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(TestDependencies.MOCKK)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_PLATFORM)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_API)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_PARAMS)
                runtimeOnly(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_ENGINE)
            }
        }
        val desktopMain by getting {
            dependsOn(jvmMain)
            dependencies {
                api(compose.preview)
            }
        }
        val desktopTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(TestDependencies.MOCKK)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_PLATFORM)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_API)
                implementation(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_PARAMS)
                runtimeOnly(TestDependencies.JUNIT5_ENGINE)
            }
        }
    }
}

sqldelight {
    databases.create("ImageryDatabase") {
        packageName.set("net.tactware.map.dal.imageryrepo")
        srcDirs("src/commonMain/imageryDatabase")
    }

    databases.create("ImageFolderDatabase") {
        packageName.set("net.tactware.map.dal.imageryfolderrepo")
        srcDirs("src/commonMain/imageFolderDatabase")
    }
}


android {
    namespace = "net.tactware.map"
    compileSdk = AppConfig.COMPILE_SDK
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = AppConfig.MIN_SDK
        targetSdk = AppConfig.TARGET_SDK
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.0"
    }
}
```